# Anti-seize type and location to use for brakes

Tags: brakes, brake-rotor, brake-calipers, anti-seize

I am going to be doing my first full break job - rotors and pads as well as rear parking brake. I've been studying up on it.

The information pertaining to what anti-seize to use and where to use it appear to differ.

For example, one source made a note of saying not to use silver anti-seize but instead copper. Another used silver.

Also some people put the anti-seize on the ends and back of the break pad for lubrication as well as on the metal running that the break pad rests on in the caliper.

What anti-seize should be used?
Where should it be used?
Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with copper or silver grease is that it can effect the ABS sensors.

Although rare it is becoming common enough for manufactures to specifically list it as a reason to void a warranty.

I have also found that copper grease can dry out and seize up sliders. For example Mitsubishi will also void the warranty on the calliper carriers if there is evidence of copper grease.

You can now get synthetic grease purposely for brake lubrication. Pagid, Bosch and Mintex all do a product called brake lube. It doesn't tend to dry up and leave any residue.

Comment: I have purchased some brake lube for the purpose of lubing the calliper pins. So the recommendation is to use this not anti seize?

Comment: Yes use a small amount of brake lube rather than traditional metal based grease on the ends of the pads and where they run in the calliper

Comment: Syl-Glide or any of the expensive Permatex "racing" etc ceramic brake lube.  I've never heard in 40+ years anyone suggesting brake components receiving anti-sieze.  I can't imagine how aluminum or copper or any other non-ferrous containing lube would affect a hall-effect ABS sensor, but there's little to no point in anti-sieze anyway on parts that move relative to each other.

Answer (score 0):

I've always used copper grease and never had any reason to try anything else really.

The lubricant is used not only to help the sliding parts of the brake mechanism to operate freely, but it also helps prevent the brakes from squealing.

With regards to its application. You put a small amount of grease on the main contact points were the shoes/pads meet the brake calipers, slave cylinders and shoe backplates. Be VERY careful to avoid getting any copper grease etc on the brake lining material or discs/drums.